# A concept of strong free will that's able to be represented in category theory?

Tags: kant, free-will, categorical-imperative, category-theory

Are there any such things as category theories where the category is an indeterminist/postdeterminist form of free will? Let's say, maybe it is a category where each object is an object of choice, there are initial choices and terminal choices, etc.

Or, this concept of free will actually requires going between subsidiary categories. So it involves metacategories or what are called "*n*-categories," maybe? I tried looking for an essay where they work something out along these lines, but the sort-of closest I got was an essay about category theory being applied to an analysis of the deontic logic implicit in the Canadian legal system. I'll try Googling something like "deontic logic and category theory" and see what that gets me.

Alt./specified formulation of the issue: talk of "nontrivial automorphisms" is given in category theory, incl. where this intersects higher set theory. Now Kant says that the three main phrasings he expresses the categorical imperative in are at heart equivalent/enter into some sort of equivalence relation with each other. So perhaps we could speak of nontrivial automorphisms of the category of categorical imperatives. Since Kant has autonomian free will and moral concepts as integrally linked, perhaps he could be construed as allowing that deontic categories could be repurposed as categories of free will. (Or, then, his own "categories of freedom" are such things, except insofar as his use of the word "categories" is not identical in meaning to modern use in the higher-mathematics context.)

Comment: Once you have a category theoretic representation for that problem, what will you do with it?

Comment: @Frank one set theorist, Penelope Maddy, has proposed an *in re* realism about mathematical objects, but I think it was uncertain whether the surrogates she selected from the physical world (arbitrary subregions of spacetime) are plentiful enough to satisfy the reference maps from *ante rem* realism. I wonder if the range of the sheer will-to-refer, however, then, could allow for an *in re* realism (where mathematical objects exist as encoded into free will, which will is capable of referring to whatever it wills to refer to as such).

Comment: I think in re realism, and even realism tout court, are fool's errands.

Comment: @Frank my idea at an angle from that is that the distinction between realism and fictionalism can be undermined, and the question of existence itself negated (perhaps) on every level, including the mathematical one. But before Quine/category theory, the schools of philo-o-math were evidentialism-minded. Each portrays its evidence base as *the* evidence base (semiotic formalists: physical symbols; intuitionists: formal physical intuitions; predicativists, noncircular intensions; Platonists, intellectual intuition), and in a foundationalist vein.

Comment: So I think it is not really a "coincidence" that Quine's set theory has circular sets, including a circular universal set, and that he was so fundamentally involved in the matter of the indispensability argument for mathematical realism. The holism of his reasoning, here, is of a piece with the coherentism of category theory. If we switch to a logic that doesn't use the concept of existence *at all*, then, we could evaporate the question of realism (but also of fictionalism), maybe.

Comment: How do you respond to Benacerraf's argument against the realism of numbers?

Comment: And I'm very curious to understand what a "logic without the concept of existence" would be talking about.

Comment: First, the meaning of "category" in Kant (or Aristotle) is so far removed from that in category theory that I wouldn't read much into similar sounding phrasing. And second, category theory is deeply antithetical to free will, or any kind of intrinsic metaphysics, because it systematically eliminates objects as such and turns them into mere placeholders in a web of external morphisms, playthings at their mercy. Metaphysically, it is a descendant of Leibniz's relational ontology, only completely stripped of monads to which (Kantian) free will could potentially attach.

Comment: @Frank Conifold mentioned a logic from Quine that doesn't use quantifiers, "predicate functor logic." On the Benacerraf end of things, if we confine attention to choosing between Zermelo and von Neumann format for rewriting number terms as set terms, I did come up with an alternative to the empty set that rules out vN format at least until the number 3, but which eventually rules out Z format across the board (by negating the singleton axiom as a whole). But otherwise I would appeal to pluralism and say that numbers are whichever sets we *will* them to be, so to say.

Comment: @Conifold I realize that the word "category" is not same in meaning from Kant/whoever to Saunders/MacLane, but still the SEP article on CT says those two guys were minded to use the word because it was used in (translations of) Aristotle, Kant, and others. At any rate, for those who interpret category theory as concerning the nature of logic (or the nature of the multiplicity of logics) it would not seem (to me) to be difficult to formulate a category theory of deontic logic, and again I saw one example of this being done (for some reason with a Canadian focus).

Comment: @KristianBerry So it sounds like Benacerraf wins: I would say that what exists is precisely what we encounter but _cannot will_. What does your empty set look like?

Comment: @Conifold Now I am confused :-) which category theory are you talking about here?

Comment: @Frank, I start with an ur-element **u**, and it's defined so that the only set it is an element of is the set {**u**} = 1. But so then 2 cannot be {**u**, 1} but has to be {{**u**}}. After that it's OK for vN format to kick in and have 3  = {1, 2}, although for aesthetic reasons I assume (in the theory) that it makes more sense for 4 to be the first ordered pair {2, 3} or then {2 , {2}}. But later, the axiom of singleton-minus kicks in and the corresponding ordinals can't be construed as iterations of Zermelo format.